# Building a stacked bar chart from a list within a dictionary matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dictionary which contains a list for each value, for example:

```
countries = {'NG': [1405, 7392], 'IN': [5862, 9426], 'GB': [11689, 11339], 'ID': [7969, 2987]}
```

Is there a way to build a stacked bar chart from this dictionary using each value as a bit of the stack for each key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the bar_stacked example from the matplotlib site, use the `bottom` argument to `bar` to shift the bars, one on top of the other.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

countries = {'NG': [1405, 7392], 'IN': [5862, 9426], 
             'GB': [11689, 11339], 'ID': [7969, 2987]}

c = []
v = []             
for key, val in countries.items():
    c.append(key)
    v.append(val)
v = np.array(v)

plt.bar(range(len(c)), v[:,0])
plt.bar(range(len(c)), v[:,1], bottom=v[:,0])
plt.xticks(range(len(c)), c)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of doing a bar chart with the data you've given. We just loop through the items in the dictionary. Sum them up and plot a bar for the value (this will be the top-most part of the bar chart). Then plot the bottom part second - this will plot it 'on top of' the summed value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = [u'#348ABD', u'#A60628']

d = {'NG': [1405, 7392], 'IN': [5862, 9426], 'GB': [11689, 11339], 'ID': [7969, 2987]}

i = 0
for key,vals in d.items():
    plt.bar(left=i, height=sum(vals), color=cols[0])
    plt.bar(left=i, height=vals[0], color=cols[1])
    i = i + 1

plt.xticks(range(len(d)), d.keys())
```

Which produces

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation for `Axes.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar).

This function takes an argument `bottom=` which defines the bottom level of each bar. In your case, you have to call `bar()` twice, once for the first set of values (and an implied value of `bottom=0`, which I set explicitly here to highlight the difference) and a second time with the second set of values and `bottom` equal to the first set. That way, the second set of bars rests on top of the first set.

```
countries = {'NG': [1405, 7392], 'IN': [5862, 9426], 'GB': [11689, 11339], 'ID': [7969, 2987]}

plt.bar(range(len(countries)), np.array(list(countries.values()))[:,0], bottom=0, align='center')
plt.bar(range(len(countries)), np.array(list(countries.values()))[:,1], bottom=np.array(list(countries.values()))[:,0], align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(countries)), countries.keys())
plt.show()
```

[image]